# Replace strings with space using Sed and Regex

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I want to replace all occurrences of {{password}} or {{  password }}  or {{password }} in files with some string using `sed` i am able to remove with know number of spaces , but could not remove all combinations.

i could replace using , but not all combinations

```
sed -i -e "s/{{ password }}/$password/g" test.sql
```

Comment: note that you'll have to make sure `password` variable doesn't contain ``\`` or `&` or the delimiter character which `/` in the example used above.. see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed

Comment: also, as a good practice, I'd use `'s/{{ password }}/'"$password"'/g'` to avoid double quotes conflicting with sed command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of spaces is arbitrary, then you could search for zero or more spaces (`*`) instead of just one space () with something like `{{ *password *}}`.

Comment: if you are using regex, I often use "\s" instead of " " just to be sure there are not tabs or other whitespace characters "posing" as a regular space.